Counter example for an algorithm to decide if flow network has unique min-cut
Let N=(G,s,t,c) flow network and let m be the number of nodes in the network. given a max flow f*
Note that al the capacities are positive integers
Given the following algorithm to determine if there exists more than one min-cut:

Find all the vertices that reachable from s in the residual graph, mark this group of nodes as S

Increase capacity of each edge that crosses the cut by $\frac{1}{2m}$ , mark the number of those crossing edges h

Calculate the new max flow, mark f'

If $|f'| < |f*| + \frac{h}{2m}$ return true, else false


So I know that the algorithm work only for one side, if the algorithm returned true there are at least 2 min-cuts, the problem is when it returns false, it does not necessarily mean that there is a unique min-cut, but I can't find an example for that case.

What does 1\2m and h\2m mean? What exactly is your question?  I don't see a question here.  Where did you encounter this task/problem?  Can you credit the original source?

I encourage you to use Latex/Mathjax to format mathematics.  See here for a short introduction.

I edited the question. it is a question from a previous exam in a course that I'm taking but it's not in English so the source doesn't really matter. The question is, given this algorithm I should determine if it give correct answer for the problem it try to solve, I know that it does not but I can't come up with a counter example
